# script-tutorials.com Colorwheel change color of different div

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas

I'm using this colorpicker to change the color of an element: http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-color-picker-canvas/. Clicking on an element opens the colorpicker, and selecting a color changes the color of the div originally clicked on.

```
<div id="preview"></div>


$('.preview').css('backgroundColor', pixelColor);
$('.preview').click(function(e) { // preview click
                  $('.colorpicker').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
                  bCanPreview = true;
                  });
```

Clicking on the element opens the colorpicker as expected, however, when I try to change the click element, for example, by adding a button:

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="click" />


$('.preview').css('backgroundColor', pixelColor);
$('.button').click(function(e) { // preview click
                  $('.colorpicker').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
                  bCanPreview = true;
                  });
```

Absolutely nothing changes. To clarify, I want to be able to click a button, have the colorpicker open, and when a color is selected, change the color of the original element. What can I do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are calling the selector with a dot instead of a pawn when it's an id (not a class) the referencer:

```
$('.button')
```

As id:

```
$('#button')
```

Comment: Oh, okay. So it works originally because preview is the class and id of the original element?

Comment: If you only have this: `<div id="preview"></div>` (with no class specification whatsover) and this is working: `$('.preview')` then jQuery has changed completely since the last time I used it.